# FOSFacebookBundle + FosUserBundle Email exist in the BDD

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, fosfacebookbundle

I have a special use case I can not solve. When the user click on `Facebook Connect` and find an similar email in my DB. I want to ask the user if the account belongs to him.

If the answer is yes, he needs to connect with his account and then add the `Facebook ID` in the DB.

If the answer is no, I create a new user in the DB and log in.

I don't find the best way to do this. Can someone help me ?

Comment: I have implemented a facebook provider and in the method LoadByUsername. When it detected the Email exist, I try to transmit data to a controller. I don't know if it is the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In controller you can check whether email exists in DB or not using fos user bundle user manager

```
$user = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserByEmail($email);
```

After user confirms, you can use implemented facebook provider to do necessary action.

between,
I have a question for you,

> "If the answer is no, I create a new user in the DB and log in."

how do you create a new user with same email (assuming email is unique)?

Comment: I check already if the email exist but in my case, the problem involved when i want to ask if the account belongs to the user who try to connect.

Comment: Why you want to confirm gain? as user had already verified his email with facebook. I would ignore that step. btw, what is the problem?